# Host's camera on network game isn't working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

So, I'm doing an FPS game in Unity5, and some days ago I started looking at [multiplayer tutorials](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking) at the official site of Unity.

However, I changed some bit of the code to fit in an FPS, but I had a problem when started doing this. The client's camera moved fine, but the host's one did not: It used the client's camera to see, but his player to move, sort of a third-person view.

All players have the same code, and the camera has a Network Identity with Local Player Authority turned on. Also, it has this C# script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class VisionControl : NetworkBehaviour {

void Start () {

    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void Update () {
    if(!isLocalPlayer){
        return;
        }
    transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (-Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y")*5.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I removed the VisionControl script and putted this one on the player's movement script:

```
    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer ()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        FindObjectOfType<Camera> ().gameObject.transform.position = this.transform.position+new Vector3(0f,0.5f,0f);
        FindObjectOfType<Camera>().gameObject.transform.SetParent (this.transform);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your camera should not have a network identiy.
It is used only by the local clients to get a perspective of the game world, so they do not need to be networked.
Each camera exists on the current client.for the current client only.
Each game instance should have 1 camera running, that of the Local Player.

Attach a simple non-networked camera component to your player prefab and test again.

Comment: The host works fine, but when a client moves its camera, the host moves the camera too. I think this is because the clients send information to the host and the host interprets it.

Comment: That is why cameras are not to be networked...
There should be no communication over cameras among players/server.
Each player has a camera for his own use, networking a camera is not a good idea....

Comment: Yeah, but how do I do for the camera to only be locally and not transfer data in any way?

Comment: Remove every Network component from the camera ( NetworkIdentity, NetworkTransform etc ) and just keep a simple Camera component.

Follow my original answer instructions.
Just add a camera component to your player prefab and dont network it in any way

Comment: Doesn't work. It transmits the data because the player has a NetworkIdentity. It needs it to be the player.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.... Post some code about how you move the camera.
Also post a screenshot of your game object components

The player has a NetworkIdentity, but the camera is not the player.The camera should just be a component attached to the player,not the player itself

Comment: Yeah, I know what you're saying, that it is an object with no network components so it should be local. But it is not. The code for the camera is the one adobe.